# Running Javascript without access to head of document

Tags: javascript, function

Here's my problem; I maintain a website for a church. They want a page called stream.htm which will show their live stream from YouTube if they are streaming live or the most recent video in a particular playlist if they aren't. I have 2 iframes on the page with different embed codes for the different streams.

The thing is that the site the church uses to host the website uses a strict wysiwyg interface. You can enter "code" mode but this just lets you paste html code inside a div in the document. It doesn't allow you to actually add javascript functions to the head of the document.

How can I implement a javascript function that will toggle the visibility of the 2 iframes based on system date/time if I can't access the head of the document?

Comment: Have you tried just adding a `script` tag with your functions in your HTML?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need access to the document head to run javascript - you can happily have javascript anywhere in the HTML document in `<script>` tags (although, it's not best practice to have it outside head / footer).

Your only concern should be to make sure you define your javascript function **before** you try to call it.

Whether the site will allow the javascript (i.e. not escape it or remove it entirely via validation) is another question.

Comment: When I attempt to put the code in directly I get an error that I am trying to use document without defining it first.

Comment: Please supply your code as part of your question - if you are getting an exception like that your javascript is probably getting executed fine, and instead it is an issue with your code

Comment: Ok, my code is the following: <script type="text/javascript">
    var live = document.getElementById(stream);
    var arch = document.getElementById(archive);
    var strm = "1";
    if(strm === null || strm === "0") {
        arch.style.display = "block";
        live.style.display = "none";
    } else {
        live.style.display = "block";
        arch.style.display = "none";
    }
</script>

Comment: It is possible that your host / website is blocking the javascript someway, as document should be a global variable. I would try using `window.document` instead, and also inspect the HTML source of the page produced from the host to see if they have changed anything / implemented something to block the JS.

Comment: The site is using Javascript for menu and login functions; so unless it is something conflicting with the existing scripts, I don't think it is blocking anything.